# Selenium Webdriver - No such element exception when i try to click button in a popup

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I tried every possible way before posting the question. stuck since many days.. lost patience. please help

The following is the html code.

[image: html code]

my java code to click button:

```
//wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@id='dialog-form-level2']/following-sibling::div//button/span[text()='Acquire Only']")));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='dialog-form-level2']//div[@class='ui-dialog-buttonset']/following-sibling::div//button/span[text()='Acquire Only']")).click();
```

I made sure that pop up is not a new frame, tried to switch windows, tried xpath, tried css - nothing works

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead. Also, your HTML doesn't show the `SPAN` that you are attempting to click with code. When you repost it, make sure you expand everything so that it's visible.

Answer (score 0):

Did the xpath can find the button successfully when you try the xpath manually in browser DevTool,  means your code correct, but need a long time to wait the pop-up loading before script to find the button.

To quick verify it's waiting time issue, just to add a long sleep before the find button, if sleep work, repalce sleep to wait.

I noticed you comment the wait code line in your given code snippet, and another issue is you not pass the second arguemnt for `wait.util()` to tell the max waiting time, try give a value for 20 or 30 seconds after you provide it's a waiting time issue.